# 他のオブジェクト指向言語に経験のあるプログラマがRubyを覚えるための簡潔な日本語の説明

Tags: ruby

Rubyを紹介する必要があって、和文で一通り書いてある文書を探しています。

他のオブジェクト指向言語を知っていると仮定して、短時間でざっと読める簡潔なものが良いのです。入門書は沢山あるのですが、そういうものでなく、ざっと味見が出来るような文書が望ましいのです。

私の知っている範囲だと、英文なら、定番中の定番である、Agile Web Programming with RailsのAppendixがまさにそういう文書なのですが、残念ながら一番新しいものの和訳がまだ無いので、紹介しにくい感じです。

もしご存じでしたら教えてください。

Answer (score 4):

Ruby on Rails チュートリアルの第4章のこのあたりから眺めてみるのはいかがでしょう？

http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby?version=4.0#sec-strings_and_methods

もちろん、Ruby on Railsのチュートリアルの一部なので、Railsの経験やWebアプリケーション開発の知識を前提としている部分も多いですが、オブジェクト指向言語である程度経験がある人であれば、わからないところは飛ばしたり勘で想像しながらでも、短時間でRubyの特徴的なエッセンスに触れることができるように思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なかなか良い感じですね。これをまず紹介してみようかと思います。

Answer (score 4):

初めての Ruby という書籍がオススメです。

http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4873113679

書評はこちらが参考になると思います。

http://blog.livedoor.jp/dankogai/archives/51077051.html

Comment: どんなところがおすすめか、具体的に共有していただけると検討する時に助かります。質問では「入門書ではなく、ざっと味見が出来るような文書」を希望されていますが、そこを超える良書なのか、とか。書評の抜粋でもいいかと思います。(回答は後から[edit]できます)

Comment: ありがとうございます。yugui さんのですよね。前に見た気がします。入門書として良いですよね。ただし、探しているのが「簡潔な」文書なので、ちょっと入門書だと長いと思うのです。。。ざっくり味見してもらいたいという気分がとても強いです。

この書籍について少し残念なのは、1.8ベースで（1.9についてappendixはありますが) 2.2 が出ようかというタイミングでは、そろそろちょっと古いかなーと思っています。更新版でることを望んでいます。

Answer (score 3):

さっくりと味見したいという要望ですと、[やわらかRuby](https://gist.github.com/udzura/7548163)
という文章があります。

あえてRubyの特徴らしいところにスポットライトを当てているため、おそらく「他のオブジェクト指向言語に経験のあるプログラマ」なら、Rubyらしいところがわかるような作りになっているかと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。これ、なかなか良いですね。もうちょっと文章親切だと良いかと思いますが、必要充分ではあります（文章まで求めるのは贅沢かもですね。。）。

Answer (score 2):

[Ruby リファレンスマニュアル](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/doc/index.html) はどうでしょうか。もともとはリファレンスですが、序章にRubyとは何かということから言語仕様まで載っています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。必要充分とは思いますし、これしかなければ読むという気もしますけれど、上で説明したAppendixと比べると、簡潔さと実用性という点で比較にならない感じです。

Answer (score 2):

Railsですが、これどうでしょう。Railsのチュートリアルをかなり簡潔にした感じなので紹介レベルだといいかもです。ハンズオンでツイッターみたいなアプリだとすぐ作れるよ！的な内容です。
[小学生でもわかるRuby on Rails入門](http://openbook4.me/projects/92)

Comment: ありがとうございます。どちらかというと、RailsというよりRuby言語自体の方を求めています。Railsの説明には、これを参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

他のオブジェクト指向に親しんでいて、ざっと味見ということですが「[7つの言語 7つの世界](http://shop.ohmsha.co.jp/shop/shopdetail.html?brandcode=000000001902&search=978-4-274-06857-7&sort=)」(オーム社)はいかがでしょうか。1つの言語に1週間(実際は3日分の内容)かけて取り組んでみようという本です。(元はpragprogの本）

`Ruby`以外の言語も含まれていますが、インタプリタでのHello Worldから始まって、最終的にメタプログラミングの基礎の基礎あたりまで触れることが出来、`Ruby`のパワフルな側面を知るのにも良い内容かと思います。

---

また、`Appendix`についてですが古い版(Second Editionでは確認できました)にはきちんとしたチュートリアルがあるものの、最新版ではRubyの説明に第4章が割かれているなど本の構成が版によって異なります。ですので、いつの版の`Appendix`かも明記されたほうが良い気がします。

Comment: たしかに、そうですね、あの本も良いかもしれないですね。読んでいます。手元にないので和訳のクオリティがちょっとわからないのですが、多分平気でしょうね。。また、例のRailsの本は全ての版を読んでいるのですが、スッカリ忘れていました。御指摘ありがとうございます。確認します。